# "iframes" within Windows Forms' form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to prepare single window with static parts and variable content just like iframes at HTML (with menu and the page itself). How to do so via the Windows Forms Designer? I could use tabs and maybe somehow disable the possibility to manually switch between them... but I guess there is some more elegant way to do so, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an user control and place it on the form.  User control will be your 'iframe' and the rest of the form will be 'static' contents.

Comment: There are other ways, but that is most common, I guess.